# Nodejs server connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am completely new guy to Node js. i can able to connect sql database with following code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var client = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: 'root',
database:'Arun'
});

client.query(
'SELECT PersonID FROM Persons WHERE City="chennai"',
function (err, results, fields) {
console.log(results);
client.end();
                            }
);
```

How can i display this results in browser window

```
http://localhost:8000
```

i know some srver js needed for this one. but i dont know how can i do this. pls help me

Comment: You need to start a http server, listen on port 8080 and send it to the browser, using something like `http.writeEnd(200, results);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use nodejs express framework:

it is easy just read the api here.

http://expressjs.com/

I think this will solve your purpose.

here is some code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    var client = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database:'Arun'
   });

   client.query(
       'SELECT PersonID FROM Persons WHERE City="chennai"',
       function (err, results, fields) {
           console.log(results);
           res.send(results);
           client.end();            
        });        
});

app.listen(8080);
```